# Mysql/Php - Displaying the single product page selected from a list

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP page that's the product list as depicted below. The last column is the link to the single product page reporting all the details about that product.

```
ID     |   Title      |   LINKTOPAGE
-------|--------------|------------------
001    | ProductTitle | $ID(001)-->Link to the single_product_page.php
002    | ProductTitle | $ID(002)-->Link to the single_product_page.php
003    | ProductTitle | $ID(003)-->Link to the single_product_page.php
```

The above table is generated by the following loop:

```
 <?php
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($risultato)){
               echo '<tr>
                         <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
                         <td>'.$row['post_title'].'</td>
                         <td>'.'LinkToSinglePage >>'.'</td> 
                    </tr>';
          }?>
```

I have already prepared the single page that retrieves data from this query:

```
SELECT 
     p.id as ID, 
     p.post_title, 
     p.post_status,
     p.post_excerpt as shortdesc, 
     p.post_content as longdesc
     FROM mg_posts as p
     WHERE p.ID= 13323
     GROUP BY p.ID
```

What I am trying to do it is to link the "linktoProductPaGe" to the single page. If I am not wrong I should replace the ID=13323 with the variable that stores the ID of the selected product in the list.

Any suggestion on how?

Comment: yes you need to replace

Comment: Use a prepared statement and also use a variable representing the post ID.

Comment: Tim, what I miss is how to pass the variable (ID product) of  products_lists.php into p.ID of the single_product_page.php, replacing as in the example '13323'.

Comment: Basically, the link in the last column, should capture the ID in the first column, moving to single_product_page.php, replace the ID into the query and execute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like that, for example (get method):

Product list (products_lists.php):

```
 <?php
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($risultato)){
           echo '<tr>
                     <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
                     <td>'.$row['post_title'].'</td>
                     <td>single_product_page.php?product_id='.$row['id'].'</td> 
                </tr>';
      }?>
```

And in your product detail page (single_product_page.php), you can get the id like that:

```
<?php $product_id = $_GET['product_id']; ?>
```

Hope that will help. :-)

Comment: Goin to try it Rafael.

Comment: And you should prevent SQL injection by using for example PDO for your SQL querries. ;-)

Comment: Not easy for me but I will try.

Comment: First part was ok, let me see the destination page.

Comment: Rafael, on the single product page, I should replace the value into "WHERE p.ID= 13323"  with "WHERE p.ID=$product", is it right?

Comment: "WHERE p.ID=$product_id"

Comment: your solution was ok! thanks Rafael. I am going to implement the security aspect now.

Comment: Great to hear! Thanks! This is actually my first contribution on stackoverflow.com :)

Comment: Rafael I am having on issue on single_product_page.php since when I am in a field a push the return button, I get an issue related to the syntax. The weird thing is that if I reach the page from the products_list, everything is fine. If I push return button staying in a field I get the error message

Comment: What kind of field are you talking about?

Comment: In each field I select in the single_product_page, if I push return button I get this error "Notice: Undefined index: product_id in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gest/pages/singolo_prodotto.php on line 5
Query non valida: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY p.ID UNION ALL SELECT ps.id, ps.post_title, ps.post' at line 22"

Comment: Ok. I answered in a new post. ;)

Comment: Do you have fields in that page? Is it a page where you can edit the products?

Comment: Yes, they are input fields such as description, price etc..but currently they display only information. I didn't implemented yet the UPDATE function.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having an syntax error when opening the page single_product_page.php from the browser, you should add the following code:

```
if(!isset($_GET['product_id']){ 
    echo 'No product selected.'; 
}else{ 
   // Your code to get the product infos 
}
```

Comment: in the else part, I will include the sql query I use to retrieve information, right?

Comment: The issue is that being positioned in a field of the single_product_page and push the ENTER Key, the the script doesn't find the $product_id variable and provide me with this error: --> "Notice: Undefined index: product_id in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gest/pages/singolo_prodotto.php on line 7
Query non valida: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY p.ID UNION ALL SELECT ps.id, ps.post_title, ps.post' at line 22<---

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the tag "action" of your HTML form is either not defined or has the value "singolo_prodotto.php".

So, at the beginning of the PHP code of your page "singolo_prodotto.php", you should add the following code, as explained further up :

```
if(!isset($_GET['product_id']){ 
   echo 'No product selected.'; 
}else{ 
   // Your code to get the product infos 
}
```

And when you'll have to manage the edition of the product, you'll have to add another condition like that :

```
if(!isset($_GET['a_field_of_your_html_form']){ // Or "$_POST['a_field_of_your_html_form']"
   // Your product edition code 
}
```